# React Native Hooks: unable to display values in return() from useEffect function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

Using react hooks with firebase real time database with a project Im working on for the first time, the data is being retrieved and logs in the console. BUT I am unable go move out side the useEffect function to display values on the screen! Would really appreciate some help!

videoArray needs to be put in a FlatList, as you can see in the code bellow videoArray logs values in the console in useEffect function. However, once I move out that function to add it into a FlatList it is null because the values are in a local function.

My question is, how am I able to pass value of videoArray (in useEffect) into the FlatList?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { FlatList, View, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { Center } from '../components/Center'
import { Video } from 'expo-av';
import firebase from '../firebase'
const videoRef = firebase.database().ref('videoCollaction');

export const FeedScreen = ({ }) => {

    let [videoArray, setVideo] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {

        videoRef.on('value', (childSnapshot) => {
             videoArray = [];
            childSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                videoArray.push({
                    key: doc.key,
                    video: doc.toJSON().video,
                });
            })    
        })

        // able to log values only here 
        console.log('working:', videoArray); 

    });

        // get video uri from firebase (testing)
        // readVideo = () => {
            // var collection = firebase.database().ref("videoCollactionvideo" + "/video").orderByValue();
            // console.log('uri', collection); 
        // }



    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <Text>Feed Screen</Text>

            {/* null here: need values to show up here*/}
            {console.log(" test",videoArray)}

            <FlatList
                data={videoArray}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                    return (
                        <View>

                            <Text style={{ fontSize: 35, color: 'red' }}>Video:...</Text>


                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('pressed')}><Text style={{ color: 'blue' }}>Expand</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    );
                }} keyExtractor={({ item }, index) => index.toString()}>
            </FlatList>

        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const temp = []; // temp array
    videoRef.on("value", childSnapshot => {
      childSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        temp.push({
          key: doc.key,
          video: doc.toJSON().video
        });
      });
      setVideo(temp); // update state array
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: one other thing :) I'm not 100% sure how it is intended to work, but the way you declared `temp` - it will be getting results in addition while keeping old values that already were there. If you declare it within `.on` callback - then trigger from firebase will override list completely

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are trying to update the State Hook (`videoArray`), but you are doing it the wrong way (it shouldn't be modified directly). Instead, use the `setVideo` update method which you created with the Hook (`let [videoArray, setVideo] = useState([]);`):

```
useEffect(() => {
    videoRef.on('value', (childSnapshot) => {
        newVideoArray = [];
        childSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            newVideoArray.push({
                key: doc.key,
                video: doc.toJSON().video,
            });
        })    
    })

    // able to log values only here 
    console.log('working:', newVideoArray); 
    setVideo(newVideoArray);
});
```

Check out [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) for more information on how to use this specific hook (the *Optimizing Performance by Skipping Effects* section might be especially of interest).

In essence, this functionality is similar to your Functional Component's stateful counterparts ([React.Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) or [React.PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent)), where:

> Constructor is the only place where you should assign this.state directly. In all other methods, you need to use this.setState() instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { FlatList, View, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { Center } from '../components/Center'
import { Video } from 'expo-av';
import firebase from '../firebase'
const videoRef = firebase.database().ref('videoCollaction');


export const FeedScreen = ({ }) => {
    let [videoArray, setVideoArray] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {

        videoRef.on('value', (childSnapshot) => {
            const newVideoArray = [];
            childSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                newVideoArray.push({
                    key: doc.key,
                    video: doc.toJSON().video,
                });
            })    
            setVideoArray(newVideoArray);
        })

        // able to log values only here 
        console.log('working:', videoArray); 

    }, []);


    console.log('State also working :) >> ', videoArray); 


    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <Text>Feed Screen</Text>

            {/* null here: need values to show up here*/}
            {console.log(" test",videoArray)}

            <FlatList
                data={videoArray}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                    return (
                        <View>

                            <Text style={{ fontSize: 35, color: 'red' }}>Video:...</Text>


                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('pressed')}><Text style={{ color: 'blue' }}>Expand</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    );
                }} keyExtractor={({ item }, index) => index.toString()}>
            </FlatList>

        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}
```